# Remove duplicates in numbered array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

How do I remove duplicates from a array if it only should check in position [1] (fruit name)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => Apple
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2 
        [1] => Pineapple 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => Apple
    ) 
)
```

Comment: foreach over the parent array, add each value to a new array where the key is `[0]` from each array. Duplicates will just overwrite each other. You can then use `array_values` if you wanted to reset the keys back to zero.

Comment: What if i have more numbers/informations than the fruit name? Will it still work?

Comment: Oh, I was backwards. You can create the array with the key `[1]` as well. Either one would work.

Comment: could you show me? foreach {$array as $item} $array2 = $item[1];

Comment: You showed the starting array. It would be helpful if you showed what the array should look like after duplicates are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just foreach over the array and add each value to a temporary array where the key is `[1]` from each array. Duplicate values will just overwrite each other. You can then use `array_values` afterwards if you wanted to reset the keys back to numeric.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$arr = array ( 
    array (1, 'Apple'),
    array (2, 'Pineapple'),
    array (1, 'Apple')
);
echo "Before:\n";
print_r($arr);

//create a temp array
$tmp = array();
foreach($arr as $v){
    $tmp[$v[1]] = $v;
}
//reset the keys
$arr = array_values($tmp);

echo "\n\nAfter:\n";
print_r($arr);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/KCECc

Answer (score 2):

Use array_unique :

```
$arr = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
```

the SORT_REGULAR flag compares the elements normally without changing types

> http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Its not removing my duplicates.

Comment: That's interesting that [it does work](https://3v4l.org/vVgAA), but the manual specifically states `Note: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays`, which this is.

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help you.

```
$array =array ( 
'0' => array ( '0' => 1, '1' => 'Apple'),
'1' => array ( '0' => 2, '1' => 'Pineapple' ), 
'2' => array ( '0' => 1, '1' => 'Apple') ,
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $values){
    $trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$values);
    $new_array[$values[1]] = $values; 
}
```

print_r(array_values($new_array));

Out Put :

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => Apple
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => Pineapple
    )

)
```